# Aborting installation. yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd /home/ficho/workspace/storybook-tutorial has failed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg, npx

I am not able to create a new react app.
So far it worked great, but today I had to install yarn and since I would get this error, when I tried to create a new react app:

```
➜  workspace npx create-react-app storybook-tutorial

Creating a new React app in /home/ficho/workspace/storybook-tutorial.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.10
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning react-scripts > babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no
 longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
warning react-scripts > jest > @jest/core > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > request-promise-native@1.0.9:
 request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now
 deprecated request package, see
 https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning react-scripts > jest > @jest/core > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > request@2.88.2: request has been
 deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.3.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
error postcss@8.2.4: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^10 || ^12 || >=14". Got "13.8.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd /home/ficho/workspace/storybook-tutorial has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting storybook-tutorial/ from /home/ficho/workspace
Done.
```

I use Ubuntu 18.4.

I tried clearing cache: `yarn cache clear` and updating npm `npm install -g npm@latest`

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your node.js would solve this problem.